# Points change position on zoom in D3 scatterplot

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I made a scatterplot of some data points following [this](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch06.html#_the_scatterplot) example - works fine.

Now I tried to make the plot pan- and zoomable based on [this](http://bl.ocks.org/peterssonjonas/4a0e7cb8d23231243e0e) implementation. Somehow my points change their position suddenly as soon as I start panning. They also move slowly in wrong directions while zooming. I assume something is wrong with my zoom transformation, but I don't see the mistake..

```
function zoom() {
    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);

    svg.selectAll(".dot")
        .attr("transform", transform);
}

function transform(d) {
    return "translate(" + xScale(d.lng) + "," + yScale(d.alt) + ")";
}

var zoomBeh = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(xScale)
    .y(yScale)
    .on("zoom", zoom);

var svg = d3.select('svg')
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .attr("class", "chart")

svg.call(zoomBeh);
```

Scaling of my points, maybe relevant.. (y scaling analog):

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([d3.min(data, function (d) {
        return d.lng;
    }), d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.lng;
    })]).range([padding, w - padding]);


svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("cx", function (d) {
        return xScale(d.lng);
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return yScale(d.alt);
    });
```

and axis:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(6);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
```

Full fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Krxldfx/kkwLops9/).

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the cx and cy values in your zoom function:

```
function zoom() {

    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);

    svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .attr("cx", function (d) {
    return xScale(d.lng);
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
    return yScale(d.alt);
});

}
```